# Google-Analytics | Referral Execusion List not Showing

Tags: android, google-analytics

Am integrate google analytics to my mobile app. In referral page it saw spam referrals, by googling i found that to exclude the spam referrals i can enter the domain name to the "Referral Execusion List". But i didn't found that menu inside Tracking Info menu. Please help me out to how to enable the option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Broadly there are two wrong assumptions in your questions

a) **Apps have referrers** - not really. A "referrer" is when I click a link and end up at your tracked property. No link on the web will lead me to the screen of an app.

b) **Referral Exclusion will filter referral spam** - again, not really. The purpose of the referral exclusion list is to maintain the original campaign source and in doubt that defaults to direct. Entering referral spam urls would not make them go away, it would merely attribute  them to the wrong channel (direct). They would still inflate the number of sessions and pageviews. You would use filters (e.g. exclude filter on the referring url) to filter out spam.

Happily this also means referral spam is not a problem when you track an app.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but there are referrals that works for mobile app installation

Answer (score 0):

For referral spam you should filter it out through a custom filter > exclude campaign name > Spam sources (can use RegEx). You also can create a hostname include filter which will help with this as well.

If you were to use the referral exclusion list, it would simply label those sessions as direct instead of removing them from your reports.